# What is the relationship of $\mathcal{L}_1$ (total variation) distance to hypothesis testing?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, information-theory, decision-theory

[Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) (a.k.a. relative entropy) has a nice property in hypothesis testing: given some observed measurement $m\in \mathcal{Q}$, and two probability distributions $P_0$ and $P_1$ defined over measurement space $\mathcal{Q}$, if $H_0$ is the hypothesis that $m$ was generated from $P_0$ and $H_1$ is the hypothesis that $m$ was generated from $P_1$, then the Type I and Type II errors are related as follows:

$$d(\alpha,\beta)\leq D(P_0\|P_1)$$

where

$$D(P_0\|P_1)=\sum_{x\in\mathcal{Q}}P_0(x)\log_2\left(\frac{P_0(x)}{P_1(x)}\right)$$

is the Kullback-Leibler divergence,

$$d(\alpha,\beta)=\alpha\log_2\frac{\alpha}{1-\beta}+(1-\alpha)\log_2\frac{1-\alpha}{\beta}$$

is called binary relative entropy, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are probabilities of Type I and Type II errors, respectively.

This relationship allows one to bound the probabilities of Type I and Type II errors.

I am wondering if something similar exists for [Total Variation distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures):

$$TV(P_0,P_1)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{x\in\mathcal{Q}}\left| P_0(x)-P_1(x)\right|$$

I am aware that

$$2(TV(P_0,P_1)^2\leq D(P_0\|P_1)$$

Is there more?

Unfortunately, I am not very well-versed in hypothesis testing and statistics (I know the basics and have pretty good background in probability theory).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a bit of an informal argument towards a lower bound I recently learned during a lecture.

Suppose we have two probability measures $P_0(\cdot )$ and $P_1(\cdot )$, and suppose I reject $P_0$ when the event $A$ occurs.  So,

$
\begin{align}
\textrm{Type I error} + \textrm{Type II error} &= P_0(A) + P_1(A^C) \\
&= P_0(A) + [1 - P_1(A)]\\
&= 1 + [P_0(A) - P_1(A)]\\
&\geq 1 + \inf_{A}[P_0(A)-P_1(A)]\\
&= 1-\sup_{A}[P_0(A)-P_1(A)]\\
&= 1-TV(P_0 , P_1)
\end{align}$

Comment: this is a neat answer -- thank you very much!  I am just curious, for what class was this lecture and what textbook (if any) is used for this class?  I think that your argument is formal enough, and it is definitely useful (as it lower-bounds the hypothesis testing errors), but I would like to read the material "in the neighborhood" of this...

Comment: It's an Asymptotics course taught by [Mark Low](http://statistics.wharton.upenn.edu/people/faculty.cfm?id=601).  No textbook, though.  We basically discuss a lot of the research he's done in the last 15 or so years, so his publications would be the equivalent of the course textbook.

Comment: There's a very small subtlety hiding in the step that leads to the RHS of the fourth *equality*. Writing that as $1 - \sup_A[P_1(A) - P_0(A)]$ makes it slightly clearer.

Comment: @cardinal I believe you're right.  There's another subtle step hidden:  $TV(P_0, P_1)=\sup_A (|P_0 - P_1|)$, so you need to convince your self that $\sup_A (|P_0 - P_1|)=\sup_A (P_0 - P_1)$ (which doesn't take much convincing).